# Performance problem with nested *ngFor loops used to display hierarchical data

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular8

I’m new to angular framework and I have a performance problem with nested *ngFor loops used to display hierarchical data.

1. *ngFor - 10 Items ( Level 1 ) extension panel for each item
2. *ngFor 10 Items ( Level 2 ) grid list to display the content
3. *ngFor 5 Items (Level 3 ) 5 button toggles and 2 select controls

To avoid loading all the data, I’m setting the collection for 2nd *ngFor based on current opened panel from level 1.

The entire page is very slow when I’m expanding a panel or when I’m trying to press a button toggle.
Note: I do not change the collections with these actions.

For debugging, I put a function in each ngFor to return the collections. I saw that each time I press a button toggle, angular is redoing all the iterations in all *ngFor directives multiple times.

I don’t understand why all the iterations are necessary each time I change a control. How can I improve performance in this case?

Code sample reproducing the problem on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbs8hs)!

Comment: Use trackby function, check this:https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description

Comment: Thanks @Chellappan, but angular is still doing all the *ngFor iteration when I change a control. If I understand correctly, trackBy is used when you add/remove items in collection.

Answer (score 1):

you can improve a bit the perfomance using a variable "index" and make "content" visible only if this value is the selected accordeaon

```
<!--I put the *ngFor in the own mat-expansion-panel-->
<mat-expansion-panel 
          *ngFor="let itemLevel1 of this.rootItem.children;let i=index"
          [expanded]="false" 
           <!--see that pass, itemLevel1 and "i"-->
          (opened)="onOpenLevel1Panel(itemLevel1,i)">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      ...
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>   
    <ng-container *ngIf="i==index" >  
         <div *ngFor="let itemLevel2 of this.selectedItemChildren;">
            ....
         </div>
    </ng-container>
<mat-expansion-panel>
```

In OpenLevel1Panel, we use the variable index

```
  index:number=-1;

  onOpenLevel1Panel(selectedItem: Item,index:number): void {
    this.selectedItemChildren = selectedItem.children;
    this.index=index;
  }
```

FutherMore, I think that the "options" are the real cause to slow the app

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo, actually **ng-container** with the *ngIf condition is having a significant improvement. Looking at the HTML while navigating on panels I saw that the content is removed when the index is changing. I realize now that closing the panel was just hiding the content. However, for me is still a mystery why Angular is redoing the iterations when I change a control, it should be only when I change an object or the entire collection.

Comment: The performance issue when toggle a button is not related to the nested *ngFor directives. After a few more test I realized that I have no delay if I switch to mat-radio-group. It was a performance issue with the mat-button-toggle material component. https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17252

Answer (score 0):

You pointed out a real problem, **nested data**.
*ngFor built for simple flat iterations.
From here you can try to combine some tricks and techniques:

1. Optimize rendering by using 'trackby'. It will help but can't solve it.
2. Try to flat data by using 'smart-dumb' components approach, see [this example](https://medium.com/@jtomaszewski/how-to-write-good-composable-and-pure-components-in-angular-2-1756945c0f5b)
3. lazy handle each level separately, You can even handle any recursive deep level (click opens new level)
4. Optimize rendering by using  [virtual scroll](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview), this will not render invisible data, good for long lists.